# Hook 'profile_update' dont get me the roles updated, only the basic info

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, synchronization, hook

I have this code that takes care of when an administrator or any user changes the information of a user from the backend, send that information to an endpoint to synchronize users.

```
// Función para enviar la actualización de perfil de usuario al endpoint
function send_profile_update_to_endpoint($user_id, $old_user_data = null, $userdata = null) {
    // Eliminar la entrada de caché correspondiente a los datos del usuario
    wp_cache_delete($user_id, 'users');

    // Obtener los datos del usuario modificado
    $user = get_userdata($user_id);

    $token = '-----------'; // Token de autorización

    // Verificar si el usuario tiene el rol "VIP" para establecer el valor de "partner"
    $partner = in_array('vip', (array) $user->roles);

    // Construir el array de datos del usuario para enviar en el body de la solicitud
    $user_data = array(
        'name' => $user->first_name,
        'surname' => $user->last_name,
        'email' => $user->user_email,
        'password' => base64_encode($user->user_pass),
        'passwordMD5' => $user->user_pass,
        'original_email' => $user->user_email,
        'username' => $user->user_login,
        'business_name' => '',
        'country' => '',
        'zip_code' => '',
        'phone' => '',
        'newsletter' => '',
        'partner' => $partner ? true : '',
        'member' => ''
    );

    $body = array('users' => array($user_data)); // Construir el cuerpo de la solicitud

    // Configurar los encabezados de la solicitud
    $headers = array(
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
        'X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
    );


    // Realizar la solicitud HTTP POST

    $response = wp_remote_post('https://test.com/api/users/sync', array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'headers' => $headers,
        'body' => json_encode($body)
    ));

    // Verificar la respuesta de la solicitud
    if (is_wp_error($response)) {
        // Ocurrió un error al realizar la solicitud
        error_log('Error al enviar la actualización de perfil al endpoint: ' . $response->get_error_message());
    } else {
        $response_code = wp_remote_retrieve_response_code($response);
        $response_body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);

        // Verificar el código de respuesta y registrar el resultado en los registros
        if ($response_code === 200) {
            // La solicitud fue exitosa
            error_log('Actualización de perfil enviada al endpoint correctamente. Respuesta: ' . $response_body);
        } else {
            // La solicitud no tuvo éxito
            error_log('Error al enviar la actualización de perfil al endpoint. Código de respuesta: ' . $response_code);
        }
    }

}
```

The problem I have is that when I look at the updated information, the basic information fields such as first name, last name, etc. are the new ones that have been modified, but if the roles are also modified from the admin panel, those new roles will not detects them. In other words, the roles are not updated at that point in the flow.

Example:

If a user is called "William" and has a "super" role

and change to "Alfred" with the role "vip", the hook detects the new name but does not detect the change of role.

I think the problem I'm having is that when an admin modifies a user's information from the WordPress user panel, including roles, the 'profile_update' hook is fired before the roles are officially updated via the wp_update_user() function. Therefore, when my code is executed in that flow, the roles that arrive in the request body are the old ones instead of the new ones.

**I need that when the information of a user is modified, be it the basic one, the roles or both, send that information to the endpoint**

I have tried several hooks and none get the roles

// Hook to update the user profile from the administration panel
add_action('profile_update', 'send_profile_update_to_endpoint', 10, 3);

// Hook for when the user's role is changed
//add_action('set_user_role', 'send_profile_update_to_endpoint_roles', 10, 3);

// Hook for updating the user profile from the frontend panel
add_action('personal_options_update', 'send_profile_update_to_endpoint', 10, 3);

// Hook to update the user profile from the WooCommerce "My Account" panel
add_action('woocommerce_update_customer', 'send_profile_update_to_endpoint', 10, 1);

I get this in $userdata:

```
(
[ID] => 289
[user_login] => pruebesita 23
[user_pass] => $P$BA8J63LF.1W5iH1gYPqhROT6s5Sb4y0
[user_nicename] => pruebesita-23
[user_email] => nose+34@gmail.com
[user_url] => 
[user_registered] => 2023-06-08 16:08:14
[user_activation_key] => 1686240496:$P$BfcKS1xXubceLVaE8fFjPXCVaMnJmO0
[user_status] => 0
[display_name] => manu eee
[first_name] => Manuel P
[last_name] => P M
[nickname] => vaale
[description] => 
[rich_editing] => true
[syntax_highlighting] => true
[comment_shortcuts] => 
[admin_color] => fresh
[use_ssl] => 0
[show_admin_bar_front] => true
[locale] => 
[facebook] => 
[instagram] => 
[linkedin] => 
[myspace] => 
[pinterest] => 
[soundcloud] => 
[tumblr] => 
[twitter] => 
[youtube] => 
[wikipedia] =>
```

)

not the roles like i see in the DOC https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/profile_update/